# Should SSL certificates be configured in Tomcat when using Apache server as front end?

Tags: tomcat, apache2

I'm using Apache server to receive HTTPS traffic, and I want it to forward the request to Tomcat using mod_jk.

The configuration of the Apache site has everything to handle HTTPS on 443 for a specific domain, also configured mod_jk, but it seems the requests are not being forwarded and I'm not sure if I need to do anything on Tomcat too to handle the request. I think if Apache receives HTTPS, I can forward HTTP to Tomcat, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: You can use Apache to terminate the https connection and then fetch it with straight http. If you open a connection to port 80 from Apache system to Tomcat does it answer? Does a tcpdump show the Apache system making an outbound connection ?

Comment: Please add your mod_jk config for httpd and your AJP connector config from server.xml. Also, make sure your mod_jk config has been applied to your SSL vhost.